# How do I query SQLite Database in Android?

Tags: database, android, sqlite

I successfully created the Database and inserted a row however I cannot Query it for some reason. My Droid crashes everytime.

```
          // Create a new row of values to insert.
          ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
          // Assign values for each row.
          newValues.put("value", "kunjan");
          // Insert the row into your table
          myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newValues);

          String[] result_columns = new String[] { "value" };

          // I GET AN EXCEPTION HERE
          Cursor allRows = myDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, result_columns, null, null,
              null, null, null, null);

          if (allRows.moveToFirst()) {
            String value = allRows.getString(0);
            TextView foo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            foo.setText(value);
          }

          allRows.close();
          myDatabase.close();
```

I get this exception

```
no such column: value: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT value FROM mainTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the problems with the original post

- Creating a table that has already been created. I wrote "if not exists" in the "create table" instruction.
- Not handling Exceptions properly. I got a lot of exceptions in the creation of the table, quering it etc. I sorrounded all these operations with try-catch
- Using hard coded values for Column names - This made it harder to verify if I was querying the column that I had created.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are creating table with only one column(value) and you are trying to read the column-1 instead of column-0 from the cursor. If that still not helps, please add try-catch block and capture the logs

```
String value = allRows.getString(0);
```

Comment: Changed it. Thanks. But I get an exception while querying.

Comment: could you please try  query(String  table, String[]  columns, String  selection, String[]  selectionArgs, String  groupBy, String  having, String  orderBy)
instead of the query() you used, i am not not much aware the of the field 'distinct' and how does it affect